# Ruby on rails - nested attributes: How to do a find or create of the nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, nested-attributes

I have a `Bill` model with nested `Customer` model.
The `Customer` model has a phone number with a uniqueness validation on it.
While creating the bill I want to fetch the existing record based on the phone number or create a new one if such doesn't exist.
How should I do it in a `RESTful` way?

Comment: On further research and googling I found out that I could add an :id key to the customer_attributes and rails updates the record instead of creating a new. In other words I have to issue a customer_attributes[:id] = find_by_phone(customer_attributes[:phone]).id
What I don't understand (yet) is on which hook in the life cycle of the model (before/after, validate/save) or even one which model(customer/bill) should I do this.

The solution seems to be fairly trivial in this case but it becomes complicated in deeply nested fields.

Answer (score 2):

you would use the find_or_create_by method which would look something like this in your case:

```
fetchedRecord = Bill.find_or_create_by_phone_number(customer.phone_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the find_or_create or find_or_create_by methods (which are dynamically created). A little Googling should get you there the rest of the way, I think.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like these answers are what you are asking.

Forget about Rails, my question would be, what's the RESTful way to create a resource that might already exist? Should you POST to the resources (list) URL, and then expect a HTTP status code of 201 if the resource was created and a 200 if it already existed?

Seems like this should be spelled out in a standard somewhere.

By the way, this is how I am handling it--with status codes.

Answer (score 0):

I place mine in the the association callback `before_add`

Comment: Please place comments in the comments section.